# Add Network Share as a Trusted Site

Tags: network-share, windows-10, security-zones

I'm having the problem [described in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13208768/1366033) when using Visual Studio T4 templates on a network share.  The [solution specified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23174276/1366033) is to add your file share to your Trusted Sites Zone via Internet Explorer.

Here are two more guides on doing the same process, both via IE

- [MSDN - Specify Your Network Servers as Trusted Sites](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb496428.aspx)
- [Loading projects in Visual Studio using the Shared Profile feature in Parallels](http://blog.florianb.net/2009/10/31/loading-projects-in-visual-studio-using-the-shared-profile-feature-in-parallels/)

While I am an admin on my machine, some of the settings on IE are locked by our enterprise system administrator:

[image: IE Security Zone Settings]

While it's certainly a possible route to go to change our enterprise wide trusted sites, it seems heavy handed for a use case that really only affects me, as someone with full administrator over their own machine to boot.

Is there any other way to add a **Trusted Site**?

As a workaround, and proof that this is the root of the issue.  When I use the same exact files on `C:\Projects` it works fine, but `H:\Projects` (which maps to a network share) throws the error.  Yes, I could just migrate everything to C Drive, but we have a process already in place that makes that option inconvenient.

Comment: What did your enterprise system administrator have to say?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, looking to gather info before bugging dev ops

Comment: You should have gone to them first. This isn't really something we can help you with.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I mean fair enough I suppose.  Regardless of the asker's organizational status, it's a question about if there's a vehicle for changing a setting on a PC.  That seems within the wheelhouse of what ServerFault is for, but you'd know better than I.

Comment: The answer won't do you any good, because _you can't change the setting_.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, agreed, I can't change *that* setting - the question is "Is there any **other way** to add a Trusted Zone?" Turns out the answer is yes (see my answer below identified by my sys admin).  The underlying frustration is that Trusted Zones are just acting as a shortcut for triggering UAC, which I have the permission to accept or reject and would be happy doing so on a case by case basis. However, some products (Visual Studio in this case) just have poor error handling when attempting an action that would normally invoke UAC and throw an error instead.